# CSS class conflicts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was developing my website using my own custom stylesheets, but then decided to use a bootstrap instead.
The problem I have in particular is a conflicting class. I have a HTML element

```
<div class="dashboard-stat blue">
```

However, i have 2 CSS classes called blue: one that is defined as .blue and the other is .dashboard-stat.blue.

I want latter to be used, however, when I open up the page and using inspect element, i found that both are used, however the .blue class is used on top of the .dashboard-stat.blue class.

Is there a way to use the more specific class ONLY? I do not want to remove my old classes yet because I want to make the changes to the style one piece at a time.

Comment: `.dashboard-stat.blue` isn't another class `.blue`: it's the same class. Maybe you're speaking of a selector (the part before `{` in your stylesheet) or the whole rule (the selector, `{` and `}` that follows and everything in-between)?

Comment: They are two different classes with selectors `.blue` and `.dashboard-stat.blue`

Comment: Also, when inspecting element, what you see is that both rules apply because both selectors match this element and its classes. But that isn't to say every declaration (property and value) apply. If a property is found in only one rule, well it applies. If it's found in both rules, only the one with the most specific selector will apply.

Comment: These are 2 different *rules* with 2 different *selectors*. One rule has a selector made of only 1 class `.blah`, the other one has a selector made of the same class `.blah` and another one `.other`, that will match only HTML elements having both classes. The latter selector can be written `.blah.other` or `.other.blah`.

Comment: But both rules are applying in this case, the question is how to get **only** the more specific one to apply

Answer (score 3):

You can add a !important onto your class property if you want. Normally I'd only recommend this as a last resort as it may make your life difficult in the future, but this seems like a proper case for it.

```
.blue {color:#00f!important;}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I've thought about using that, but I'll have to make changes to MOST of the classes in the bootstrap library (which could be extensive)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.blue:not(.dashboard-stat)` (and the current `.dashboard-stat.blue`). Although this won't work in IE <= 8.